# How to call Start() method of multiple thread class instances in one statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, syntax, tuples, delegates

Need syntax help, is there any way of calling the same method of multiple instances in one statement, like the way we assign values to multiple variables?

```
var t1 = new Thread(SayHello);
var t2 = new Thread(SayBye);
var t3 = new Thread(SayGoodbye);

(t1.Name, t2.Name, t3.Name) = ("Thread1", "Thread2", "Thread3");

// any way to call t1,t2, and t3's Start Method in one statement like above
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
t3.Start();
```

Comment: You can put your threads in a list and iterate through that

Comment: that cannot be done in one line, I have to create a list first, then iterate over it.

Comment: (new List<Thread> { t1, t2 }).ForEach(_=> _.Start()); one line

Comment: What is so important about having it done in one line?

Comment: Besides the fact that is might be possible somehow - *WHY* in the world would you want to do that? Code should be as clear and understandable as possible. Minifying it results (most of the time) in the opposite.

Comment: Do you literally mean one line, or one [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sorry, I mean in one statement, I have edited my question.

Comment: @MarkusSafar That is so true, just want to do that "to minimize repetition"

Comment: A list and a foreach loop is a repetition?

Comment: @IamK No, I mean calling multiple times Start Method, is a kind of repetition.

Comment: @FKEinternet in one statement, to "minimize repetition"

Comment: @Basit, There would be no point in creating a thread if you weren't going to `start()` it. Maybe it's not the `start()` calls that are being repeated here. Maybe where you're repeating yourself is by creating the three "SayHello" threads in the first place.

Comment: @SolomonSlow not maybe, three SayHello threads are pure repetition. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the Start() method of multiple objects in one statement as you would assign the same value to multiple variables in one statement:  ***The Start() method is an element within each object, not the same piece of code attached to each one.***  The closest you're going to be able to come is in [IamK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468608/iamk)'s comment

```
(new List<Thread> { t1, t2, t3 }).ForEach(_=> _.Start());
```

which is a valid construct, as opposed to the merely conceptual one I thought up

```
(t1, t2, t3).Start();
```

Comment: LamK's comment isn't "close." It's right on target. It is a _single statement_ that starts all three threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're right in that it's a single statement that calls each of the Start() methods.  What I meant by "closest" was closest to the idea there might be one method to call that's used by all of the objects, as opposed to each having a Start() method.

Answer (score 0):

To have all thread starts in a single line, just remove the line breaks after `t1.Start();` and `t2.Start();` (just kidding).

I assume, you want to start all threads at *the same time* (down to a nanosecond). That's not possible - as it is not possible to assign multiple variables *at the same time*. The line where you assign the threads names (via a `Tuple`) is just a c# syntactic sugar. It results in multiple statements as can be seen e.g. on [Sharp Lab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTUcADOgHYCGAtgKZwANJ158Yw7v1QBuRkyLVJAiaPEip9ALzpqAIgAucXcIMxj6A6l21ZSJgF9k9oA=) (I've linked a sample).

Answer (score 0):

You can start your threads like this:

```
(t1, t2, t3).Start();
```

...but in order to do that you must include in your project this extension method:

```
public static void Start(this (Thread, Thread, Thread) tuple)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tuple.Item1);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tuple.Item2);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tuple.Item3);
    tuple.Item1.Start();
    tuple.Item2.Start();
    tuple.Item3.Start();
}
```

Obviously this is not practical. If you have four threads you must add another extension method with four arguments, and if you have some other class with a `Start` method you must write yet another set of extension methods for that class etc. Long story short the C# language currently (C# 10) cannot do this thing automatically for you.